# How can I change the default animation for a WinJS Flyout?

Tags: windows-8, winjs, flyout

I'd like for my winJS Flyout to slide rather than fade in. How can I modify the default animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the animation codes for the FlyOut lies in the js Ui.js in the javascript library which is actually not editable. Instead of creating a flyout you can always go for a `div` and animate it accordingly.

On the other hand, Microsoft also provides the css class for different controls including flyout so you can add your css. A better option would be to use [the Placement property of flyout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770561.aspx) and after show animate is say margin the way you would like for a slide animation.

This is just a work around see if it can help you.